# Symfony and Doctrine: cross database relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, entity-relationship, cross-database

I have two entities **Entity1** and **Entity2** with a OneToMany relation, but they live in two MySQL databases.

How can I implement those entities with their relation in Symfony?

Is it possible to create two separated bundles where to implement those entities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Doctrine, joining data across databases is not technically “supported” by a designed feature, but you can make it work by tricking Doctrine a little bit.

If you want to build a relationship between entities then they must use the same connection: same database.

The key to getting multiple databases to work is within your entity classes, you need to specify **the table name of the entity with a prefix of the name of the database to which the table belongs**. Here is an example using annotations:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\UserBundle\Entity;

use DoctrineORMMapping as ORM;

/**
 * Demo\UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORMTable(name="users.User")
 */
class User implements
{
  /* ... */
}
```

and

```
<?php
namespace Demo\PostBundle\Entity;

use DoctrineORMMapping as ORM;

/**
 * Demo\PostBundle\Entity\Post
 *
 * @ORMTable(name="posts.Post")
 */
class Post implements
{
  /* ... */
}
```

and the relation table:

```
<?php
namespace Demo\PostBundle\Entity;

use DoctrineORMMapping as ORM;

/**
 * Demo\PostBundle\Entity\Post
 *
 * @ORMTable(name="posts.Post")
 */
class Post implements
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Demo\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     **/
    private $user;

    /* ... */

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Demo\UserBundle\Entity\Site $site
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Demo\UserBundle\Entity\Site
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://techpunch.co.uk/development/using-multiple-databases-with-symfony2-and-doctrine2) an article about it.

Hope this help

Comment: Grazie! And can I set that database name string as a config parameter?  Ciao!

Comment: hi @ShinDarth with the doctrine annotation i think is not possible insert parameters but you can try with the xml annotation and put a params with `%db_name_1%` hope this help

Comment: hi @ShinDarth have you tried my solutions? Is it working?

Comment: hello @matteo, unfortunately so far I didn't have the time and I guess I won't have for I while. But I'll let you know, thanks for asking!

Comment: Hi @ShinDarth i'm only curious about this, thanks for further update

Comment: you're welcome. What about you? Did you try such a thing?

Comment: Does it work if the database are in different servers ie it uses different entity managers?

Comment: @Vinayak seems not possibile, for this trick must use the same connection: same database.

Comment: Does it create db table when running cli command? Please confirm that