# How to use variables in Symfony Doctrine ORM annotations?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, parameters, config

In short, I would like to use something like:

```
@ORM\Table(name="schemaname.tablename")
```

but replacing the "**schemaname**" string with a variable, that can be set as a configuration parameter somewhere (like in **parameters.yml** file)

Comment: I don't think this is possible and I also don't think it should ever be necessary. Can you explain why you need to have the table name non-static?

Comment: ORM do the "relation" between your database and your class. In your Entity you have getter and setter to get the variable you want. I don't understand what you want to do ^^. You cant have a table name variable. Otherwise you can try the temporary table, but I don't know how handle this with doctrine

Comment: I need to achieve the cross-database entity relations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696793/symfony-and-doctrine-cross-database-relations/

Comment: At least for me, this does not explain why you can't just hardcode the name as usual.

Comment: because a Bundle with hardcoded database names can't be reusable...

Answer (score 1):

I understand your context as a reusable bundle entity with cross domain relation to an other bundle.
I don't find anything about doctrine mapping customisation, but as your bundle can only be included once per project, I recommand you to use your bundle name as a prefix for the table. 
Like yourapp_tablename

For the crossdomain constraint, your bundle, if it is reusable can't have dependencies to external bundles. It is your business bundles which have to use the reusable bundle, not the way around. I guess you have to use interfaces if you want an external bundle to be extending your model class